# How can I persist a session when directing a user offsite, then back?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-10

Website A creates user session data and sends a request to Website B. Website B reviews information that was passed and sends a response back to Website A. Website A needs to process the response and log the info for the user session, however, the user session seems to be null upon the redirect to Website B (or on the redirect back to Website A).

Is there a way to persist the user session data on Website A?

EDIT: I will not need access to the session data on Website B, I just need it to be there once redirected back to Website A, however it seems that upon being redirected back, it has been nulled out.

EDIT 2: Add rough code sample. Problem is that upon redirecting from/to Site A, the ASP.NET SessionID is reset and the "customer" Session object is null and no longer available after returning from Site B back to Site A.

Site A

```
...
CustomerObject customer = new Customer();
Session["customer"] = customer;
Response.Redirect("https://www.siteB.com?querystring=info");
```

Site B

```
... handles needs
Response.Redirect("https://www.siteA.com?querystring=info");
```

Site A

```
 //parse response//
 string info = Request["querystring"]
```

Comment: There's a host of ways you can do this. If you have control over both Website A and Website B, a JWT is my preferred way to persist user state/session data. You could have Website B generate a JWT and Website A would then just need to decrypt and decode it, it would then have the same session/user state as Website B (assuming the JWT is made from session/user state)

Comment: Post the code you've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

You could either use [.Net Application Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/caching-in-net-framework-applications) and build a custom class around accessing that cache, and the stored data you wish to persist. Or you could do it with a database.

In both cases, you would need to generate a key that would be saved in your new persistence layer (I guess you already have a generated sessionId to start).

In the simplest scenario, you could send this key in your request and require it in the response, which will allow you to identify and retrieve the persisted session data. Maybe disposing of it when no longer required/after a period of time.